# Getting error 403 in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i have record script in badboy and generate .jmx file.
In jmeter open that file and run then display error
[image]

Comment: Did u get the resolution for getting access error in Jmeter but not in browser?
I am also getting same issue, with no clue to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP Status Code 403 stands for [Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

> The **HTTP 403 Forbidden** client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to 401, but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic (like an incorrect password).

Most likely this is due to incorrect JMeter configuration and/or missing/incorrect [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations), I would suggest the next steps:

1. Make sure you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) added to your Test Plan
2. If your application is protected with external authentication system like [Basic HTTP Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) or [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) you need to handle it properly using [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)
3. If your application is expecting some form of security token as request parameter or request header or cookie or whatever you will need to extract it from previous response using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), convert it into a JMeter Variable and add it as a parameter to the next request.

Above are general recommendations, we need to see your test plan snapshot and request/response details in order to be able to help you to get to the bottom of the problem

Answer (score 0):

can you access the request in question manually via the browser? I would assume its server configuration to deny you/require authorisation to access what you desire.  This would suggest the request is received but you are not authorised to access it

Comment: i get error in jmeter.not in browser